# iOS Quartz/CoreGraphics drawing feathered stroke

Tags: objective-c, ios, drawing, quartz-graphics, smoothing

I am drawing a path into a CGContext following a set of points collected from the user. There seems to be some random input jitter causing some of the line edges to look jagged. I think a slight feather would solve this problem. If I were using OpenGL ES I would simply apply a feather to the sprite I am stroking the path with; however, this project requires me to stay in Quartz/CoreGraphics and I can't seem to find a similar solution.

I have tried drawing 5 lines with each line slightly larger and more transparent to approximate a feather. This produces a bad result and slows performance noticeably.

This is the line drawing code:

```
CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),((int)lastPostionDrawing1.x), (((int)lastPostionDrawing1.y)));
CGContextAddCurveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), ctrl1_x, ctrl1_y, ctrl2_x, ctrl2_y, lastPostionDrawing2.x, lastPostionDrawing2.y;
[currentPath addCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(lastPostionDrawing2.x-((int)furthestLeft.x)+((int)penSize), lastPostionDrawing2.y controlPoint1:CGPointMake(ctrl1_x, ctrl1_y) controlPoint2:CGPointMake(ctrl2_x, ctrl2_y)];
```

Comment: Have you tried CGContextSetShouldAntialias function?

Comment: I had similar problems in the past using quad curves or curves with 2 control points. I could probably help if you send me the .svg of what you want to draw or at least some more info of the feather you are trying to draw

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to go ahead and assume that your CGContext still has anti-aliasing turned on, but if not, then that's the obvious first think to try, as @Davyd's comment suggests: `CGContextSetShouldAntialias` is the function of interest.

Assuming that's not the problem, and the line is being anti-aliased by the context, but you're still wanting something 'softer.' I can think of a couple of ways to do this that should hopefully be faster than stroking 5 times.

First, you can try getting the stroked path (i.e. a path that describes the outline of the stroke of the current path) using `CGContextReplacePathWithStrokedPath` you can then fill this path with a gradient (or whatever other fill technique gives the desired results.) This will work well for straight lines, but won't be straightforward for curved paths (since the gradient is filling the area of the stroked path, and will be either linear or radial.)

Another perhaps less obvious option, might be to abuse CG's shadow drawing for this purpose.   The function you want to look up is: `CGContextSetShadowWithColor`  Here's the method:

- Save the GState: `CGContextSaveGState`
- Get the bounding box of the original path
- Copy the path, translating it away from itself by 2.0 * bbox.width using `CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath` (note: use the X direction only, that way you don't need to worry about flips in the context)
- Clip the context to the original bbox using `CGContextClipToRect`
- Set a shadow on the context with `CGContextSetShadowWithColor`:

  - Some minimal blur (Start with 0.5 and go from there. The blur parameter is non-linear, and IME it's sort of a guess and check operation)
  - An offset equal to -2.0 * bbox width, and 0.0 height, scaled to base space. (Note: these offsets are in base space. This will be maddening to figure out, but assuming you're not adding your own scale transforms, the scale factor will either be 1.0 or 2.0, so practically speaking, you'll be setting an offset.width of either -2.0*bbox.width or -4.0*bbox.width)
  - A color of your choosing.
- Stroke the translated-away path.
- Pop the GState `CGContextRestoreGState`

This should leave you with "just" the shadow, which you can hopefully tweak to achieve the results you want.

All that said, CG's shadow drawing performance is, IME, less than completely awesome, and less than completely deterministic. I would expect it to be faster than stroking the path 5 times with 5 different strokes, but not overwhelmingly so.

It'll come down to how much achieving this effect is worth to you.